# Generate a list based on constraint result, using Prolog's CLPFD

Tags: prolog, constraints, clpfd

I'm attempting to implement a [Skyscraper puzzle](https://www.brainbashers.com/skyscrapershelp.asp) solver in Prolog, using constraints (CLPFD).

I've realized a great constraint would be calculating the number of times the maximum switches whilst traversing each row and column and matching it with the side clue.

Here's an example of a single row:

```
*2* [ _ | _ | _ | _ ] *3*   ->   *2* [ 1 | 4 | 3 | 2 ] *3*
```

The list `[1, 4, 3, 2]` works for clue **2** because it has 2 maximum switches (0 -> **1** -> **4**).
It also works for clue **3** because the same list reversed - `[2, 3, 4, 1]` - has 3 maximum switches (0 -> **2** -> **3** -> **4**).

I've managed to program a predicate that returns me the number of maximum switches of a list.
The issue is how to actually utilize it to generate a new constraint? I can't pass my list/matrix directly because it isn't yet initialized.

It should probably be something like:

```
calculate_max_switches(List, Switches),
% Generate a list whose Switches value is equal to the clue number.
```

Thank you.

Comment: No, other way around. You start with a predicate that generates all possible assignments, and then you apply the constraints.

Comment: For example, create a list 1..N and then call [`permutation/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=permutation%2f2).

Comment: Here is [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458945/optimizing-pathfinding-in-constraint-logic-programming-with-prolog) on this (among other things).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing your code, here is my hint, adapted from [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8530427/874024):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

skyscrape_row(Left, Right, Heights) :-
    constraint_view(0, Heights, LHeights),
    sum(LHeights, #=, Left),
    reverse(Heights, Heights_),
    constraint_view(0, Heights_, RHeights),
    sum(RHeights, #=, Right).

constraint_view(_, [], []).
constraint_view(Top, [V|Vs], [R|Rs]) :-
    R #<==> V #> 0 #/\ V #> Top,
    Max #= max(Top, V),
    constraint_view(Max, Vs, Rs).
```

that applied to your example yields

```
?- L=[A,B,C,D], L ins 1..4, all_different(L), skyscrape_row(2,3,L), label(L).

A = 1,
B = 4,
C = 3,
D = 2,
L = [1, 4, 3, 2]
A = 2,
B = 4,
C = 3,
D = 1,
L = [2, 4, 3, 1]
A = 3,
B = 4,
C = 2,
D = 1,
L = [3, 4, 2, 1]
```

Live code is available in [SWISH](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/kSHqETLd.swinb)