# What does sky-scrapper mean?

Tags: terminology

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54265886/1243762) there is a Prolog predicate with the comment

```
% replace OR sky-scrapper with call to new predicate
```

Googling has no results for the first few pages that I see to explain its meaning.

What is the meaning and origin of `sky-scrapper` as used in the comment?

Comment: Whatever. I think this is a question which only @AntonDanilov can answer but will be happy if I'm proved wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example code in link, the OP has used below style

```
  (  ":",       !, { Token = tokColon }
  ;  "(",       !, { Token = tokLParen }
  ;  ")",       !, { Token = tokRParen }
  ;  "{",       !, { Token = tokLMusta}
  ;  "}",       !, { Token = tokRMusta}
  ;  "\\",      !, { Token = tokSlash}
  ;  "->",      !, { Token = tokImpl}
  ;  "+",       !, { Token = tokPlus }
  ;  "-",       !, { Token = tokMinus }
  ;  "*",       !, { Token = tokTimes }
  ;  "=",       !, { Token = tokEqual }
  ;  "<",       !, { Token = tokLt }
  ;  ">",       !, { Token = tokGt }
  ;  "_",       !, { Token = tokUnderscore }
  ;  ".",       !, { Token = tokPeriod }
  ;  "/",       !, { Token = tokForwardSlash }
  ;  ",",       !, { Token = tokComma }
  ;  ";",       !, { Token = tokSemicolon }
```

this snippet is long(tall) like sky scraper, and thats why terminology is used IMHO

<s>and so OP is suggested to replace it 
with a more proper snippet, this are mostly to produce more `readable` and `maintainable` code</s>

Comment: Thanks.  I am the OP of the original question referenced in this question. It is correct that the code needs to be replaced or called, but it is not being replaced to be `readable` or `maintainable` it is being replaced because as the question ask, it uses `indexing` of predicates to improve efficiency. While I can't say that this answer is wrong, at present I don't think it is correct. Thanks.

Comment: Anton confirmed this in comment in original referenced answer. Thanks.

Comment: The reason I didn't think this was correct was that I was thinking it might be like [trampoline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_(computing)).

Comment: `this snippet is long(tall) like sky scraper, and thats why terminology is used IMHO`not only because of imaginary similarity between code and skyscraper but also because of a critical evaluation of original  code as inefficient (lack of indexing)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a typo for "skyscraper". The code example is probably solving a skyscraper puzzle.

[Optimizing pathfinding in Constraint Logic Programming with Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458945/optimizing-pathfinding-in-constraint-logic-programming-with-prolog/8530427#8530427)

Comment: Thanks. I am the OP of the original question referenced in this question. That question was about lexing and tokenization so there is no relation to the `skyscraper puzzle` Thanks, and I appreciate the effort but not the answer. :)

Comment: I gave this an up-vote for the effort and so that people can see that there is a different meaning.